# need my string clean using regular expression in R programming

Tags: r, nsregularexpression

My string is as below.

```
[{\"period\":\"01-06-2018\",\"count\":5},{\"period\":\"01-07-2018\",\"count\":8},{\"period\":\"01-08-2018\",\"count\":9}]
```

but I want only (only backslash) to be removed and it should look like below
(using **R programming** functions)

```
[{"period":"01-06-2018","count":5},{"period":"01-07-2018","count":8},{"period":"01-08-2018","count":9}]
```

Comment: 1) This looks like JSON content, and therefore you should probably _not_ be using regex to manipulate it.  2) Those backslashes in front of the double quotes are probably only there for display purposes, to show that they are _literal_ double quotes, and not delimiters marking the start and end of a string.

Comment: I have a dataframe  and I need to convert it to json, how to do that. How ever I used  x <- toJSON(unname(split(dataframeName, 1:nrow(dataframeName))))  but I am getting that json including those backslash. so I want to remove those backslashes

Comment: `gsub("\","",your.string)`?

Comment: @user2974951 they would need four backslashes. And it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
library(tidyverse)
somestring<-c("[{\"period\":\"01-06-2018\",\"count\":5},{\"period\":\"01-07-2018\",\"count\":8},{\"period\":\"01-08-2018\",\"count\":9}]")

library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(somestring)
```

This yields:

```
   period count
1 01-06-2018     5
2 01-07-2018     8
3 01-08-2018     9
```

Comment: thanks for that jsonlite package, it helped me to get rid of this problem, however I used jsonlite.toJSON().

Comment: Why `toJSON`?. It's already in JSON,No?